# Avplayer does not resize to full screen in iphone retina display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, ios6

I have a problem to play the video in iphone 5. The video is playing exactly in full screen in iphone but the problem is with retina display. It does not fit to full screen and leaves white thik bar on right side.

I tried the following code but it does not wirk in retina display

```
    outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    av = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:outputURL];
    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:av];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 1024, 670)];
    }
    else
    {
        [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, 480, 287)];
    }


    if([layer.videoGravity isEqualToString:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect])
    {
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    }
    else
    {
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    }
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    av.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[av currentItem]];
```

Please help me with some solution. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 6 of your code you are setting the width of your AVPlayerLayer to 480px but the iPhone 5 screen has a width of 568px (when in landscape). So this can't work.

This should fix your issue:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, self.view.frame.width, 670)];
}
else
{
    [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, self.view.frame.width, 287)];
}
```

But I wonder why you need that -20/-10 vertical offset and where those frame heights come from, maybe instead of that if/else block this could also work for you:

```
[layer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Comment: Thanx soph but the problem is I think player avplayer layer is not resizing. it still give white vertical bar

Comment: Set a breakpoint somewhere in your code above and look at the size of self.view in the debugger (po self.view). If it isn't 568px width self.view isn't setup in the right size. Is that view created from a xib?

Comment: Thanx Soph some how it works , I had to manage the width manually for Iphone retina display.